# Flash Uploader using URLUploader progress problems

Tags: php, actionscript-3, upload, progress, urlloader

I want to make an uploader using flash and PHP server. The problem is that I can't get the progress when uploading. I used the URLLoader class in actionscript 3. I don't use fileReference because I want to upload an image that is encoded from bitmap data. How do I get the progress?
P/s: Is there any way to return the uploading file's size from PHP server?

Comment: It's in the Adobe Bug System. Please, vote for this issue: 

[BUG ID 3044667](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=selectBug&CFGRIDKEY=3044667)

Answer (score 0):

.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, functionName) - should return you the progress